# find with wildcard path and export the result to a file

Tags: find, wildcards

I need to find files that match this pattern:

```
find root_folder/*/match_string/*.ext
```

"*" means any levels of folders or files. So it means any file with an extention "ext" under root_folder or its sub folder and whose full path contains a folder called "match_string", for example:

```
root_folder/f1/f2/match_string/f3/f4/1.ext
root_folder/f1/f2/match_string/2.ext
```

But the above command doesn't work. find -name  also doesn't work.

And I need to output the result list of matched files to a file for later import into zip command. It seems not to be straightforward to use ">" if cascaded commands are used.

Comment: Try this: `find root_folder -name 'match_string*' -type d`

Comment: @ ajgringo619 This gives all folder named "match_string", but I need files in those folders and their subfolders

Comment: ```find root_folder -path '*/match_string/*.ext' or find root_folder -path '*/match_string/*' -name '*.ext'```

Comment: Try not to use globbing like find path/* its unnecessary (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451486/how-to-cause-argument-list-too-long-error/451548#451548)

Comment: @bac0n That works, -path is the point.

Comment: @bac0n Please consider writing an answer, so we can upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
find /path/to/root_folder -type d -name "match_string" -exec find "{}" -type f -name "*.ext" \; > ~/file_list
```

The command will search for all folders named `match_string`, then search for all files which names end with `.ext` in them and their subfolders and list all found files with their absolute pathes. The list will be stored in `~/file_list`.

If you use

```
cd /path/to/root_folder
find -type d -name "match_string" -exec find "{}" -type f -name "*.ext" \; > ~/file_list
```

the files will be listed with relative pathes to the current directory, but the name of the current directory (which is `path/to/root_folder`) will not be displayed, instead `./` is displayed.

Comment: What does "{}" and "\;" mean, can you give some references for these? It seems that "-print" is not required.

Comment: I see, it also works without `-print`, just tested. Please take a look into `man find`, look for the `-exec`-action, also look for the examples further down. The `{}` is a placeholder for what the first `find` found, so the second `find` will search in the folder found by the first `find`.

Answer (score 2):

**Save filelist to file with "starting-point" removed ([man find](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/findutils/find.1.en.html)).**

```
pwd

  /opt/askubuntu/

find /opt/askubuntu/ -type f -path '*/askubuntu/temp/*' -name '*.ext' -fprintf /opt/backup/zip-archive-file.list %P\\n
```

**zip-archive-file.list**

```
cat /opt/backup/zip-archive-file.list

  temp/example/a/a/a.ext
  temp/example/a/a.ext
  temp/example/c/c.ext
  temp/example/c/c/c.ext
  temp/example/b/b.ext
  temp/example/b/b/b.ext
```

**Archive from file ([man zip](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/zip/zip.1.en.html)).**

```
zip /opt/backup/archive -@ < /opt/backup/zip-archive-file.list

  adding: temp/example/a/a/a.ext (stored 0%)
  adding: temp/example/a/a.ext (stored 0%)
  adding: temp/example/c/c.ext (stored 0%)
  adding: temp/example/c/c/c.ext (stored 0%)
  adding: temp/example/b/b.ext (stored 0%)
  adding: temp/example/b/b/b.ext (stored 0%)
```

**Pipe find result to zip.**

```
find /opt/askubuntu/ -type f -path '*/askubuntu/temp/*' \
        -name '*.ext' -printf %P\\n | zip /opt/backup/archive -@
```

Comment: Is fprintf/printf really needed? I didn't use them.

Comment: I use -printf|-fprintf to set the format %P which strips the "starting-point" (/opt/askubuntu/) from the result or you will get absolute path in your zip.